# How to zip a pdf or ppt file using zip.js?

Tags: javascript, zip, zip.js

I want zip a pdf or some other format like excel, ppt etc using zip.js.

How to zip this format in zip.js? I have written but I failed in generating the zip file. My requirement is to download the zip file when I click the download button. How to do this? I am completely stuck in generating the zip file.

My code is as below

```
<body>
    <a id ='file' href="http://www.brainlens.org/content/newsletters/Spring%202013.pdf" type="application/pdf" name="Sample.pdf">Sample.pdf</a>
    <input id="button" type="button"  value="Create Zip"></input>
</body>

<script>
var FILENAME = document.getElementById('file').name;//"sample.pdf"
var URL = document.getElementById('file').href;//"sample.pdf"

var zipFs = new zip.fs.FS();

function zipPDF() {
    zipFs.root.addHttpContent(FILENAME, URL);
}

function create_zip(){
    zipPDF();
}

var btn = document.getElementById('button');
btn.addEventListener("click", create_zip, false);
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFCC8/3/)

Comment: Although I've also had little luck using a HttpReader of some kind, I did find that it worked better if you specify the full URL (not relative - `http://path.to/file.pdf`